# Can you help me identify a superhero with shell submarine?

Tags: story-identification, super-hero

When I was a kid, there is a cartoon that I really want to watch again. It is about a male superhero, he transforms to superhero when he gets into the ocean. Blue colour, his head looks like ultraman, and he had a submarine looking like a shell. Can you help me?

Comment: When you were a kid?  You should specify so that we can filter by date.

Comment: Sorry, i watch it between 96-99, and the cartoon look like 80's compare to any other 80's cartoon

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [Namor the Sub - Mariner](https://www.marvel.com/characters/namor/in-comics) from Marvel Comics.

He is known as **The Mutant Prince** .

He is also described as "ultra-man of the deep who lives on land and in the sea, flies in the air, and has the strength of a thousand surface men".

Here are some images.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think there was a Namor cartoon.

Comment: Basically the AquaMan equivalent on the Marvel side. It’s interesting to see the similarities on both sides of the comics spectrum.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan Except Namor is older (although both are from the golden age, 1939 versus 1941).

Comment: Namor doesn't have blue skin.

Comment: No, i pretty sure it's not namor